# Is there any way to glow this bulb image like a real light bulb

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[this is the hanging bulb which i am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqena.png)[i am talking about this bulb which is in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJZub.png)

**i want to glow this bulb but unable to glow spent 4 hour but still not able to do. Please tell me how to do using css !**

this is html code

```
        div className="item image">
            <img src={sidimage} alt="sid" height="400" />

            <div className="light">
              <img className="bulb" src={bulb2} alt="light bulb" />
            </div>
          </div>
```

this is the css

```
.bulb{
    position: relative;
    left: 26.5rem;
    bottom: 32rem;  
}
```

i want to glow the bulb which is in the image

Comment: Hello, there is a `blur` style in css that will... well... blur an element, where if you put a blured light bulb under a non-blured one, it might look like it's glowing. Also, it'll be alot easier for other people to test your code if you provide the image in the question.

Comment: The best way is to layer more than one radial gradient and center it over the light bulb. You can add the pseudo-element ::after to the div containing the image. Performance might be better than using blur.

Answer (score 0):

just use conditional rendering on the image or set timeout if you want to toggle the image
That is really any easy task use another image with light bulb on and use conditional rendering